# Dynamically generate file package from S3 assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, amazon-s3

I have a service set up where when the user registers, they are able to download a file to their device. The file is dynamically generated from some local information from our database such custom field information (username, email, web url, etc) and then account specific assets stored on S3 (avatar, icons, background art).

I'm not sure of the best way to handle these S3 files as part of the generation process.

Using a Ruby `Tempfile` class generates a file that has a unique filename that doesn't match what we are expecting. Using Ruby's `File` class generates the files we want, but it also litters the filesystem with a bunch of files and I worry won't handle concurrent requests for the same assets properly. We're also using Heroku, and they tend to frown on that from what I read.

What's a best practice/recommended way to handle dynamically generating files based on a mix of local and remote assets and then presenting it to the user?

Comment: Can you make your question more clear? What do you mean by "some local information [...] account specific assets"?

Comment: Added some more info. Thanks.

Comment: What file format do you use? PDF?

Comment: It's a Passbook file for iOS, but it's for all intents a folder that is zipped and given a custom extension.